# Convergence of $f\in L_1(a,b)$ and a sequence of step functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Theorem:** If $f\in L_1(a,b)$ then there is a sequence of step functions $h_n(x)$ s.t. $\| f-h_n\|\rightarrow 0$ (convergence in norm)

In a textbook there is a proof that is based on convergence of the following functions in norm to $f$:

$$
    f_n(x)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  f(x), |f(x)|\leq n\\
                  n, f(x) > n\\
                  -n, f(x) < -n\\
                \end{array}
              \right.
$$

Is there the more elegant and concise proof of the aforementioned theorem?

Comment: Do you mean $\left\|f-h_n\right\|\rightarrow 0$ pointwise or almost-everywhere?. What exaclty do you mean by "elegant and concise"? $f_n$ as you defined it is *not* necessairily a step function.

Comment: Convergence in $L_1$ norm. $f_n$ aren't step functions, in a textbook the convergence $\|f-f_n(x)\|\rightarrow 0$ is proven first. Elegant and concise - without these non-step functions, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Sombrero lemma:** Let $(E,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and $f: E \to \mathbb{R}$ a non-negative mesasurable function. Then there exists a sequence of simple functions $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $0 \leq g_n \leq f$ and $g_n \uparrow f$ (i.e. $g_1(x) \leq g_2(x) \leq \dots$ and $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} g_n(x) = f(x)$ for each $x \in E$).

*Proof:* For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define

$$g_n(x) := \begin{cases} k 2^{-n}, & \text{if} \, x \in \{k 2^{-n} \leq f < (k+1) 2^n\} \, \text{for some} \, k \in \{0,\ldots,2^{2n}\} \\  2^n, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$

so, $g_n(x) = k 2^{-n}$ if $f(x) \in [k 2^{-n},(k+1) 2^{-n})$. 
[image]

Obviously, $g_n$ is a simple function, $0 \leq g_n \leq f$ and $g_n \uparrow f$. This finishes the proof.

> **Corollary** Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f \in L^1(\mu)$. Then there exists a sequence of step functions $f_n$ such that $\|f_n-f\|_{L^1} \to 0$.

*Proof:* We write $f= f^+ - f^-$ where $f^+$ ($f^-$) denotes the positive and negative part of $f$, respectively. Applying the Sombrero lemma, we find sequences of simple functions $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(h_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $0 \leq g_n \uparrow f^+$ and $0 \leq h_n \uparrow f^-$. If we define

$$f_n := g_n-h_n$$

then $f_n$ is a simple function for each $n$, $|f_n| \leq f$ and $f_n \to f$ as $n \to \infty$. Now the dominated convergence theorem yields $\|f_n-f\|_{L^1} \to 0$.

Comment: Sombrero was a mathematician ?

Comment: Maybe its the brother of Eigen - the guy who considered these special vectors :)

Comment: @saz is it possible to construct step functions to converge to $f \in L^1$ instead of simple functions?